# How to switch views from overlay button?

Tags: ios

I've made a button on an overlay which loads every time the camera is accessed. The button responds fine and I've tested it to see whether it was a problem with the selector. I am 100% it's not a problem with the selector(it responded to an NSLog string).

I want to bring up a new view every time it is pressed, but it doesn't do anything even though I've used an assortment of methods. I'm running out of ideas here, I've tried many methods but none work, and I mean none. I made sure I've imported the frameworks right, I've even made new projects and redid everything from step one to make sure it wasn't a problem with the original project.

```
}

- (UIView*)CommomOverlay  {
//Both of the 428 values stretch the overlay bottom to top for overlay function. It
doesn't cover it. 
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,430)];
UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,430)];



[FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
FrameImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44); // position in the parent view and set the
size of the button
[myButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[view addSubview:FrameImg];
[view addSubview:myButton];

return view;


}
```

The below does not work in my -(void)buttonPressed method:

```
UIViewController *viewControllerName = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
(NSString *) bundle:(NSBundle *)];
```

Comment: That will only create the viewController, you haven't told the app to present that view controller in anyway. Did you mean to use [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerName animated:YES]; or [self presentModalViewController:viewControllerName]; ?

Comment: I've tried that, in fact, my post was a typo. I had that added but forgot to paste it in the question. Still no luck, it's not doing much.

Comment: Your camera overlay view was probably presented as a modal view which doesn't have a parent navigation controller. Perhaps in your view controller which pushed the camera overlay on, you can call a method that pushes that new view controller (viewControllerName) after dismissing the camera overlay, when you press the button. You can either use post notification or create delegate for your camera overlay, to call the original view controller's method.